# Kinetic Energy - dependence of mass

Tags: energy, kinetic-theory

There are 2 equations to kinetic energy:
$\frac{1}{2} mv^2$ and
$\frac{3}{2} kT$.

By the first equation kinetic energy depends on mass, while by the second one it doesn't. How comes? So does it depend on mass? Will, for example mol Oxygen and mol Nitrogen have the same kinetic energy in the same temperature?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I would suggest looking up what those two expressions are actually for.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing two different concepts of kinetic gas theory here
(see [Wikipedia: Kinetic theory of gases: Temperature and kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases#Temperature_and_kinetic_energy)):

- $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is the kinetic energy of a *single* molecule.
- $\frac{3}{2}kT$ is the *average* kinetic energy per molecule, when you have *many* of them.

Answering your question about Oxygen and Nitrogen:
Although Oxygen and Nitrogen molecules have different masses $m$,
for a given temperature $T$ they have *on average* the same kinetic energy.

Comment: Worth noting here that we're talking about the RMS rather than the arithmetic mean.

Answer (score 0):

In this context $\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{3}{2}kT$. So the thermal kinetic energy here does not depend on mass. It is pinned to the temperature. At fixed velocity, the kinetic energy of a massive object *does* depend on mass.

Comment: If you want to make this identification (which is a good idea at times) you should note that the velocity that appears in the equality is the RMS velocity for particles of that mass in the gas: $\frac{1}{2} m v_\text{RMS}^2 = \frac{3}{2} k T$.

Answer (score -3):

Kinetic energy makes NO contribution to mass,,,,Our Teams in Eurasian polymaths' Association have repeatedly tested this at Macro- and Micro- levels . I want to assure everybody on this site that mass does not increase with increase in kinetic energy : TESTED EMPIRICALLY { rather than merely playing with a number of mathematical terms , functions ,and differentials }. I have been asked politely by StackExchangePhysics' administrators to write my answers here "carefully" . My PhD students and I have been very careful about designing experiments to assay what I have written here .

=======================================================

Comment: What about relativistic kinetic energy? $K.E.=(\gamma-1)mc^2$? Did you check in the velocity regime where this equation is important? Do you mean rest mass?

Comment: Thank you for this query ;  relativistic kinetic energy K.E.=(γ−1)mc2 was , of course  , checked in our Baysian Latin Square Experimentation Design . No confounding found { at significant levels } . Significance level was put at 97,5% . Mass does not increase with increase in relativistic  kinetic energy.